# Error in read object from txt and show it

Tags: java

The netbeans show this eroor

> Error with I/O processes
>   java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: katanemimena1.Account
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
>       at katanemimena1.ATM.actionPerformed(ATM.java:208)

and i dont understand why
this is the code

```
ObjectInputStream in =null;
Account acc =null;
try{
in =new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream( "Accounts.txt"));
while
( (acc = (Account) in.readObject()) !=null){
System.out.println(acc);
}
}
catch(EOFException ex) {
System.out.println("End of file reached.");
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
System.out.println("Error casting") ;
ex.printStackTrace();
}
catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
System.out.println("Error specified file does not exist") ;
ex.printStackTrace();
}
catch(IOException ex) {
System.out.println("Error with I/O processes") ;
ex.printStackTrace();
}finally{
try{
in.close();
}
catch(IOException ex){
System.out.println("Another IOException during the closing");
ex.printStackTrace();
}

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement your Account class from java.io.Serializable interface

Comment: a lot of thanks , but know is show me this katanemimena1.Account@1568654
but i want to show me 321 account with 1066E for example

Comment: Because You are printing your object. System.out.println(acc); By default it calls object's toString() method. You can also override this functionality by implementing also toString() method and print in any format You want

Comment: why show me the last one account i add in txt and not show all accounts of txt ?